# Decryption of Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) in an Oracle Database using weblogic datasource

Tags: encryption, oracle11g, datasource, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

I have implemented Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) in an Oracle Database
Can you please tell how to decrypt it using weblogic datasource connection?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rahul, nothing to do ... your application will access the information through the database and will receive clear text/decrypted data. The use case for Oracle TDE is that it protects data files from a database-bypass attack, as in: SysAdmin with OS access could read data from clear text data files.

Kind regards, Peter (PM at Oracle for TDE and Oracle Key Vault)